# How to connect and retrieve real-time data from a Whoop 4.0 band using Python

Tags: bluetooth, sdk, wearables

I have a **Whoop 4.0 band**, which is not connected to any account. I'd like to connect it to my laptop to read real-time data such as **heartbeat, skin temperature, and accelerometer/gyroscope data**.

## Details:

### Environment:

Laptop: M1 MacBook or i5 laptop
Programming Language/Framework: Python
Connection Type: Bluetooth

### What I have tried:

I have tried connecting the whoop to the laptop using Bluetooth or looking for it using:

> system_profiler SPBluetoothDataType

- Has anyone successfully connected a Whoop band to a computer for this purpose?
- Are there any specific libraries or SDKs available for interfacing with the Whoop 4.0?
- If someone has done something similar, could you provide a sample code or guide me on the necessary steps?

I'd appreciate any pointers or help on this. Thank you!

Comment: Hey, we received such questions multiple times in the past and my answer is always the same: I am not aware of any smart band that allows you to read out data from it's sensors. Just because the band measures values does not mean that it will be readable on its own. The smart bands I know measure and store the data, and only transmit it to a connected phone once in a while. They use their own apps with some kind of encryption to prevent users to access the data. But even when using their custom app there is no live reading of sensor data possible

Comment: ok, seems like this should be possible at least for the heart rate: https://support.whoop.com/s/article/Heart-Rate-Broadcast

Comment: Since they released the Strength Trainer functionality, I would assume that they have found a way to make it possible to read accelerometer data.

I am not surprised by encryption, but it still is an interesting exercise as there will be a lot of whoop 4.0 bands around once they upgrade to a new one. I love the tool, but I would like if it could improved in other ways, so I thought I could play with it.

Comment: I have used HR broadcasting, but that only works with whoops, which is on an active subscription and they are using the whoop app.

My assumption is that the encryption is lifted from the HR sensing when the option is activated.

Comment: You could try a generic BLE exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to scan the device for all services it offers. You might be in in luck and it uses default services. You could [edit] your question to add a screenshot (or list) of all services found